# referencia System.Net (Windows CE)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-mobile

buenas tardes,

agrego la referencia `System.net` para poder enviar correos electrónicos pero sucede que cuando agrego la referencia desde la ubicación de este, por alguna razón no me carga el `System.Net` si no `System.Net.Irda` y por esta razón el `MailMesasage` y demás no me funciona, que podría hacer o como puedo enviar un correo con `Windows CE`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aparte de poder enviar los correos estos deben de tener adjunto un archivo de excel que tiene unos datos que se diligencian,

No se como podría solucionar este problema.

Gracias

Comment: hey bro, ¿Llegaste a solucionar el problema? Saludos

Answer (score 3):

El compact framework 3.5 no soporta `system.net.mail` o `system.web.mail` pero puedes utilizar `OpenNETCF.Net.Mail` que está disponible en [SDF](http://opennetcf.codeplex.com/)

Ejemplo:

```
var message = new MailMessage();

message.From = new MailAddress("sender@midominio.com");
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient@dominio.com"));
message.Subject = "Asunto";
message.Body = "Cuerpo del Mensaje";

var client = new SmtpClient();

client.Host = "smtp.miservidor.com";
client.Credentials = new SmtpCredential("usuario", "password", "midominio");

client.Send(message);
```

---

Otra Solución es crear un `webservice` y ahí sí utilizar `System.Net` para enviar mails.

Comment: eso para enviar pero yo necesito tambien que se envie una informacion adjunto por excel yo estaba utilizando este fragmento

 objeto_mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "Pedido.csv", "text/csv"));

Me arroaj el error en  Attachment,

como se podria colocar o como seria el tema ahi, y lo otro cual es al referencia para OpenNETCF.Net.Mail

Comment: `OpenNETCF.Net.Mail` funciona similar a  `system.net.mail`, en el link que te dejé está para descargar esa librería en codeplex.

Comment: Leyendo la documentación  parece que adjuntar archivos no está implementado. Otra posible solución es crear un webservice.  De todas formas deberías aclarar en la pregunta que también quieres adjuntar archivos.

Comment: descargo lo que usted me indica y me sale carpetas con y solo archivos .CS y que es lo que se supone que uno debe instalar me siento perdido con esto

Comment: @CristianR.M tienes que abrir esa solución y compilar todo para que te genere la respectiva DLL

Comment: y ese dll queda alojado en donde, y cuando compilo me arroja 103 errores y 682 advertencias

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43799/discussion-between-alan-and-cristian-r-m).